# Pad a block of character containing a variable with printf

Tags: c, printf

I am writing a program in c, and I use the `printf()` function to display information on my screen. In my program, I have some issues padding a string containing normal characters and a `%s` flag.

Here is the piece of code I currently have :

```
printf ("<%s>\t%s\n", type, name);

// displays the following text:
//    <int>    x
//    <char>   c
//    <double**>      d
```

Due to the variation in the length of the `type` variable, using tabulations sometimes results in offsets between columns. I would like to specify that the `<type>` text can take up to 10 characters, and only start displaying the name at the 12th character, as such :

```
<int>      a
<char>     b
<double**> x
^^^^^^^^^^^^ <- 12th column
```

I've read several questions that used the `%12s` or `%-12s` to left or right pad a string. However, the part I would like to pad is `<%s>`. How can I proceed to specify its length, as it contains both regular characters (`<` and `>`) and the `%s` flag ?

Comment: You can use `sprintf` to make a string like `<char>` first, and then format that to the output.

Comment: Does `sizeof(type)` give you the length of `type`?

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks, I used this method, and it works fine. I would accept it as the answer unless someone comes up with another method inherent to `printf` without calling another method beforehand

Comment: @v7d8dpo4 no it doesn't. My type variable is declared as follow : `char type[10]`, so sizeof always returns `10`

Comment: You could do `printf("<%s>%*.0s %s\n", type, (int)(8 - strlen(type)), "", name);` but that doesn't handle types longer than 8 chars. You'd have to add another check for that.

Answer (score 0):

The -11 makes the field 11 wide, left justified for the first value.

Then there is a space between the two values.

Then the final value as is...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%-11s %s\n", "<int>" ,     "x");
    printf("%-11s %s\n", "<char>" ,    "c");
    printf("%-11s %s\n", "<double**>", "d");

    return 0;
}

<int>       x
<char>      c
<double**>  d
```

That is assuming your strings fit in 11 characters.  If it is longer, it overflows

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%-11s %s\n", "<int>" ,     "x");
    printf("%-11s %s\n", "<char>" ,    "c");
    printf("%-11s %s\n", "<double**>", "d");
    printf("%-11s %s\n", "<abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz>", "alphabet");

    return 0;
}

<int>       x
<char>      c
<double**>  d
<abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz> alphabet
```

Here is a nice offsite [cheat sheet](http://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet).